# Whitespace required before attribute error in my flex code

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder, flexigrid

In my flex code I am getting error whitespace required before attribute what may be problem below is code

```
<components:DialogButton buttonLabel="okCaption" click="{dispatchOK(event);}" enabled="okEnabled" id="_DialogButtons_DialogButton1" includeInLayout="okCaption != """ visible="okCaption != """/>
<mx:Spacer id="_DialogButtons_Spacer1" includeInLayout="cancelCaption != """ width="4"/>
<components:DialogButton buttonLabel="cancelCaption" click="{dispatchCancel(event);}" enabled="cancelEnabled" id="_DialogButtons_DialogButton2" includeInLayout="cancelCaption != """ visible="cancelCaption != """/>
<mx:Spacer width="15"/>
```

Even on this code too I am getting error whitespace required before attribute  below is code

```
<components:QuadStateImage click="{resetFilter();}" id="_FriendList_QuadStateImage1" right="7" sourceId="filterDelete" verticalCenter="0" visible="{StringUtil.trim(filterField.text) != ""StringUtil.trim(filterField.text) != "Search friends..."}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
includeInLayout="okCaption != """
visible="cancelCaption != """
```

Here, I think. Try

```
includeInLayout="{okCaption != ''}"
visible="{cancelCaption != ''}"
```

Comment: @ Timofei thanks it work ,1000s of like ,can u please help me for second one ,I m total newbie and learning thanks in advance

Comment: StringUtil.trim(filterField.text) != '' && StringUtil.trim(filterField.text) != 'Search friends...' Replace double quotes with single quotes inside attribute value. And I suppose there should be "&&" between expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem is with statement

```
visible="{StringUtil.trim(filterField.text) != ""StringUtil.trim(filterField.text) != "Search friends..."}"
```

use singele quotes for inline expression between double quote like

```
'Search friends...'
```

event better to use function

```
private function isVisible(value:String):Boolean
{
 // dosome thing
return //true or false;

}
```

and call as

```
visible="{isVisible(filterField.text)}"
```

hopes that helps